# FOS elastica ordering results by datetime

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

I'm ordering FOS elastica search results by datetime field in database.

The elastica.yml has this property set on mapping:

startsAt: { type: date, format: Y-m-d H:i:s }

But on populate i get this:

```
 [Elastica\Exception\ResponseException]                                                                                                                                  
  MapperParsingException[mapping [soccer]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: [Y-m-d H:i:s]: Illegal pattern component: i]; nested: IllegalArgumentExcept  
  ion[Illegal pattern component: i];
```

How do i specify correct format so i can search my elastica result by that datetime field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get desired result with this...

In elastica.yml

```
startsAt: { "type": "date", "store": true }
```

In my controller action:

```
            $query = new Query();
            $queryString = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();

            $queryString->setQuery('*'.$request->query->get('search').'*');
            $query->setQuery($queryString);
            $query->addSort(array('startsAt' => array('order' => 'desc')));

            $results = $finder->findPaginated(
                $query,
                array(
                    'from' => ($request->query->get('page', 1) - 1) * $limit,
                    'limit' => $limit,
                )
            );
```